# AngularJS only requesting new JSON data upon first load

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to get an app within an native iOS application and am having issues with loading dynamic data.

I've set up the **controllers** to request `JSON data` from the **iOS app** through http queries based on each page view.

When the **JSON** data changes, the web view is reloaded but it seems that angular does not request the data again but instead pulls it from cache.

Is there a way we can continually require Angular to only request data and not cache the **JSON** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a query parameter on your url

```
'my/url?' + new Date().getTime()
```

This is by far the easiest thing to make sure it's never cached.

There is also an alternative from the server side by making sure the cache expire header is set to a date in the past, thus making sure it's not possible to cache.